# Как отдать реальное имя сервера приложения который стоит за NGINX?

Tags: python, nginx, proxy, header

Есть такая  схема работы приложения nginx -> app , nginx служит в качестве реверсного прокси для балансировки , как отдать реальное имя сервера приложения (app)?  в моем случаи отдается имя сервера nginx

Comment: Что такое имя сервера приложения? Кому отдать?

Comment: Вы про HTTP-заголовок `Server`?

Comment: да про него Server. Все просто за nginx стоит python BaseHTTPServer. мне надо клиенту отдать имя этого сервера. но клиенту отдается имя nginx сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить в конфигурацию [proxy_pass_header](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass_header)

```
proxy_pass_header Server;
```

На любом уровне: http, server, location